# HTML form not posting data into MySQL database via PHP processor

Tags: php, mysql, html, pdo

**Context:**

I'm working with the following stack: HTML/CSS, PHP, MySQL to build a web app that stores and retrieves data entered to a form.

**Problem:**

When I enter data into the form (the html part of index.php) locally it is not actually POSTing that data into the mysql database I have setup and is throwing an error saying there is an unknown column.

I think that the problem is in the inserting values part. If anyone has any idea as to why it's not posting I would love any help I can get. Thanks for your time!

**Pics**:

[image: inspecting code locally AFTER inserting and submitting]

**Code**:

*index.php*

```
<?php

include("dbconfig.php");

try {

  /* connect with credentials held in dbconfig file */
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);

  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Successfully Connected!";


  /* input sanitization */
  $title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
  $overview = htmlspecialchars($_POST['overview']);
  $threat_details = htmlspecialchars($_POST['threat_details']);
  $cust_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['cust_name']);
  $fld_insight = htmlspecialchars($_POST['fld_insight']);
  $competitor = htmlspecialchars($_POST['competitor']);
  $id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']);
  $rev_damage = htmlspecialchars($_POST['rev_damage']);
  echo "data sanitized";

  /* submits data IF the submit button is pressed */
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

      /* insert the values passed into the html form into mysql database */
    $sql = "INSERT INTO comp (title, overview, threat_details, cust_name, fld_insight, competitor, id, rev_damage) VALUES ('titleBinded', 'overviewBinded', 'threatDetailsBinded', 'customerNameBinded', 'fieldInsightBinded', 'competitorBinded', 'idBinded', 'revDamageBinded')";


    $sqlPrepared = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $sqlPrepared->bindParam(':titleBinded',$title);
    $sqlPrepared->bindParam(':overviewBinded',$overview); 
    $sqlPrepared->bindParam(':threatDetailsBinded',$threat_details);
    $sqlPrepared->bindParam(':customerNameBinded',$cust_name);
    $sqlPrepared->bindParam(':fieldInsightBinded',$fld_insight);
    $sqlPrepared->bindParam(':competitorBinded',$competitor);
    $sqlPrepared->bindParam(':idBinded',$id);
    $sqlPrepared->bindParam(':revDamageBinded',$rev_damage);


    $sqlPrepared->execute();
    echo "Successfully Inserted!";
  }


  /* commit the transaction */
  if (!$conn->commit()) {
    print("Commit failed\n");
    exit();
  }


  /* close connection */
  $conn->close();

}
catch(PDOException $e) {

  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


<div class="form-style-2-heading">Create New Competitor</div>


<style>
html,body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif}
</style>
<body class="blue">

</head>


<body>



<!-- Top container -->
<div class="w3-bar w3-top w3-blue w3-large" style="z-index:4">
  <span class="w3-bar-item w3-center">Create New Competitor</span>
</div>

<div class="w3-main" style="margin-left:300px;margin-top:43px;">



<!-- SUBMIT PAGE CONTENT TO DATABASE  -->
<form method="POST">

<label id="info">
<span>Opportunity Title<span class="required">*</span></span>
<br>
<input type="text" class="input-field" name="opti"></label>
<br>
<br>

<label id="info">
<span>Opportunity Overview<span class="required">*</span></span>
<br>
<input type="text" class="input-field" name="opov"></label>
<br>
<br>

<label id="info">
<span>Competitive Threat Details<span class="required">*</span></span>
<br>
<input type="text" class="input-field" name="compdet"></label>
<br>
<br>

<label id="info">
<span>Customer Name<span class="required">*</span></span>
<br>
<input type="text" class="input-field" name="custnme"></label>
<br>
<br>

<label id="info">
<span>Field Insight<span class="required">*</span></span>
<br>
<input type="text" class="input-field" name="fldinsght"></label>
<br>
<br>

<label id="info">
<span>Name of Company Competitor<span class="required">*</span></span>
<br>
<input type="text" class="input-field" name="cmpname"</label>
<br>
<br>

<label id="info">
<span>Enter Deal ID<span class="required">*</span></span>
<br>
<input type="text" class="input-field" name="id"</label>
<br>
<br>

<label id="info">
<span>Approx. Revenue Implications<span class="required">*</span></span>
<br>
<input type="text" class="input-field" name="rev"</label>
<br>
<br>

<b>Technologies/Domains Included</b>
<br>
<br>

<label id="container">Tech1
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Tech2
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Tech3
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Tech4
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Tech5
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Tech6
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Tech7
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>
<br>

<b>Geo/Theatre</b>
<br>
<br>

<label id="container">Geo1
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Geo2
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Geo3
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Geo4
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Geo5
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Geo6
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Geo7
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Geo8
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Geo9
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Geo10
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Geo11
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Geo12
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Geo13
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Geo14
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Geo15
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>

<label id="container">Geo16
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<br>
<br>

<label><span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></label>

</form>
</div>
</html>
```

*create.sql*

```
drop database if exists comp;
create schema comp;
use comp;
create table comp (
    titleBinded VARCHAR(50),
    overviewBinded VARCHAR(255),
    threatDetailsBinded VARCHAR(255),
    customerNameBinded VARCHAR(30),
    fieldInsightBinded VARCHAR(255),
    competitorBinded VARCHAR(30),
    idBinded INT,
    revDamageBinded INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (idBinded)
);
create table technologies (
    name VARCHAR(225), 
    PRIMARY KEY (name)
);
create table geography (
    area VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (area)
);
```

Comment: Which one is the unknown column? All of them. Look at your create table statement and look at your insert statement. None of the column name match.

Comment: it's saying the TITLE one

Comment: You don't have a column called `title`, you have `titleBinded` Same for your other columns.. Furthermore you are using `:` in your bind statements, but not you query.

Comment: note aside: don't use htmlspecialchars for data sanitization, it will hurt your back in some time

Comment: You're saying I have to use **:titleBinded** in the input sanitization and query, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your create table statement contains the column names, you have to use those in your query:

```
create table comp (
    titleBinded VARCHAR(50),
    overviewBinded VARCHAR(255),
    threatDetailsBinded VARCHAR(255),
    customerNameBinded VARCHAR(30),
    fieldInsightBinded VARCHAR(255),
    competitorBinded VARCHAR(30),
    idBinded INT,
    revDamageBinded INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (idBinded)
);
```

The query should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO comp (titleBinded, overviewBinded, threatDetailsBinded, customerNameBinded ...
```

etc.

Now, you have a `:` in your bind statements -

```
$sqlPrepared->bindParam(':titleBinded',$title);
$sqlPrepared->bindParam(':overviewBinded',$overview); 
$sqlPrepared->bindParam(':threatDetailsBinded',$threat_details); ...
```

etc.

so you should use those in your query too, *without quotes*:

```
VALUES (:titleBinded, :overviewBinded, :threatDetailsBinded, :customerNameBinded, :fieldInsightBinded, :competitorBinded, :idBinded, :revDamageBinded)
```

Because you're binding your variables you can get rid of the lines where you use `htmlspecialchars()` as this does not sanitize your data, the binding in a prepared statement takes care of it.

**In a nutshell**

You have to have a form element with a name attribute. From there you can bind that variable when posted to use in the query:

```
<input type="text" name="this_input_name" />
```

If using the POST method the variable can be used in the bind like this:

```
$sqlPrepared->bindParam(':thisBoundName', $_POST['this_input_name']);
```

Your query would then look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tablename` (`this_column_name`) VALUES (:thisBoundName)
```

Take note of how the named input `this_input_name` is used to bind the parameter `:thisBoundName` and how the parameter is used as the value to be inserted in the column (created at the time the table is created).

Comment: Placeholders shouldn't be in quotes in the query.

Comment: Good catch @Barmar

Comment: @JayBlanchard so I can eliminate any $variable in the bindParam and it will still work with one argument passed?

Comment: You can do `$sqlPrepared->bindParam(':titleBinded', $_POST['title']);` @connor

Comment: @JayBlanchard but I changed the table columns to match up so in this case it's $_POST['titleBinded'] right?

Comment: No. The `$_POST` array uses the names of the form elements. If you have a form element like `<input name="title" />` then the variable will be `$_POST['title']`.

Comment: @connor I don't see a lot of your form elements having the `name=` property. You have to fix those.